# CollectionViewSource initialization raises listbox's SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, collectionviewsource, selectionchanged

May be I missed something, but I've already beat my head with this one.

I have defined CollectionViewSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="packagesViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:Package, CreateList=True}" />
```

and ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="lstbPackages"
    SelectionChanged="lstbPackages_SelectionChanged"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource packagesViewSource}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=PackageId, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Package}"
    SelectedValuePath="IdPackage"
/>
```

Also, I have code-behind packagesViewSource initialization:

```
private IQueryable<Packages> GetPackagesQuery()
{
    IQueryable<Package> query = dc.PackagesList;
    // Returns an ObjectQuery.
    return query;
}

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
   packagesViewSource =((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("packagesViewSource")));
   queryPackages = this.GetPackagesQuery();
   packagesViewSource.Source = queryPackages.ToList();
   ...
}
```

And the line

```
packagesViewSource.Source = queryPackages.ToList();
```

involves event

```
private void lstbPackages_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

and as you could guess

```
lstbPackages.SelectedItem != null
```

there.

What I do wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but your `ListBox` initializes with a no item selected, and you are setting the `SelectedItem` in your definition, so when the `ListBox` initializes it is running the `SelectionChanged` event to set the `SelectedItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you assign a source to your ListBox, a DefaultView of your packagesViewSource CollectionViewSource is created. and it has first element selected. So when assigning the source, do it in 3 step:

1. Get DefaultView for your resource, then
2. MoveCurrentToPosition(-1) on this view, then
3. assign the View with correct current position to ListBox.

Comment: As I've understand you, first two points are similar to this code-lines:
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(queryPackages.ToList()); view.MoveCurrentToPosition(-1); And how to apply the last one?

Comment: well, first better doing the things in a few lines to avoid headaches :-) and then, just simply with packagesViewSource.Source = ..., no magic :-)

Comment: Actually, nope. <br />

I used lstbPackages.ItemsSource = view; <br />

But, thanx a lot for idea! I owe ;) <br />

p.s.: Oh, my gosh! I don't know what tags to use for the line separation.

Comment: oops not awaken today, i meant packagesViewSource=view with the view value of your edit. Hope this time i'm not wrong or i'll never drink again :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following to your ListBox xaml.

```
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false"
```